# CBLite Android - Get values in second level

Tags: android, couchbase, touchdb, couchbase-lite

Using CBLite Android, and storing docs (similar to Android Grocery Sync example) like this:

```
{
     "check" : true,
     "created_at" : "2014-02-25T10:16:46.026Z",
     "text" : "Soap",
     "prices":[  { "date" : "2014-02-25" , "value" : 12 }  ]
}
```

I get value in **"text"** field ​​as shown in the documentation:

```
...
Document document = row.getDocument();
String text = ((String)document.getCurrentRevision().getProperty("text"));
...
```

But, How should I do to get the value in, for example, **"value"** field?

Thanks.

Edit:
[Getting documents](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-lite/cbl-android/cbl-android-1.0b2/index.html#reading-documents)
 [API reference](http://www.couchbase.com/autodocs/couchbase-lite-android-1.0b2/index.html)

Comment: Can you link the library? Search in the doc to something which allow you to get an array, then read the array to get value

Comment: Thank you very much!

Thanks to your comment I have done. I created an ArrayList variable, and I got the objects with .getProperty("prices")

I'm a newbie in Stackoverflow. How I can rate your comment?

Comment: I posted an answer, accept it. You cannot rate comments (except upvotes)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search in the doc to something which allow you to get an array, then read the array to get value.